# flutter dart timestamp to time code isn't converting properly

Tags: flutter, datetime, dart

```
var timeinres = DateTime.fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch(jsonResponse['data']['time_in'] * 1000);
```

print result is flutter:

```
{err: 0, data: {id: 14, user_id: 1, time_in: 1617004588}
flutter: 1970-01-20 02:10:04.588
```

Comment: Can you share what the json response holds?

Comment: Your `time_in` is in seconds. You need to multiply by 1000000 to convert to microSeconds[1000*1000]. But don't you use .fromSecondssince epoch if you are getting it inseconds?

Comment: yes i think i copied this code from online . so changing it to fromSecondsSinceEpoch and 1000000 fix the issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch` instead of `fromMicrosecondsSinceEpoch`.

```dart
var timeinres = DateTime.fromMillisecondsSinceEpoch(jsonResponse['data']['time_in'] * 1000);
```